# How to use document.getElementById on two different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use `getEleementById` to display two different elements with two unique IDs on different pages. One is for the main index page and another is for the project page. The code below works on the index page but doesn't work on the project page. But if I get rid of the call in animation1, then it works on the project page. **Any reason why `document.getElementById` can only be used once even though it's being called on two unique ids?**

```
function displayTitle(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.display = "block";
}

function animation1() {
  displayTitle("main-bnb-logo");
  var title1 = new TimelineMax();
  title1.staggerFromTo(".title span", 0.5,
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 0, bottom: -80},
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 1, bottom: 0}, 0.05);
}

function animation2() {
  displayTitle("project-title-content-wrapper");
  var title2 = new TimelineMax();
  title2.staggerFromTo(".project-title span", 0.5,
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 0, bottom: -80},
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 1, bottom: 0}, 0.05);
}

   $(document).ready(function() {
   animation1();
   }, 1000);

   $(document).ready(function() {
   animation2();
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Note that you're not checking to see if `document.getElementById()` returns a `null` result, which will cause an error and that'll show up in your browser console.

Comment: Isn't it because the animation is still going when it should pass to the next $(docment).ready(...)?

Comment: To answer last part: `document.getElementById` would work any number of times as long as that element with passed id exists in the DOM

Comment: Which begs the question why are you using `getElementById` if you're using jQuery?

Comment: I don't think it's because the animation is still working. They both are called on both pages, but the id is unique to each individual page. So on the home page it executes both animation1(); and animation2(); but only animation1(); does anything because home has that unique ID. Same-but-opposite on the project page.

Comment: I think it's because of exception caused by element not present. When you go to second page, animation1 runs and tries to modify style of element which doesn't exist which causes error in JS file and stops execution of animation2. In case of main page, animation 1 works as it's written before calling animation2, so by the time animation2 causes error animation1 has succeeded. Adding null check in "displayTitle" after fetching element should work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Like Tapas said in the comments, I needed to do a null check on the displayTitle function:

Updated code:

```
function displayTitle(id) {

  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  if (elem == null) {
    console.log('no id selected');
  } else {
  elem.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function animation1() {
  displayTitle("main-bnb-logo");
  var title1 = new TimelineMax();
  title1.staggerFromTo(".title span", 0.5,
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 0, bottom: -80},
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 1, bottom: 0}, 0.05);
}

function animation2() {
  displayTitle("project-title-content-wrapper");
  var title2 = new TimelineMax();
  title2.staggerFromTo(".project-title span", 0.5,
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 0, bottom: -80},
  {ease: Back.easeOut.config(1.7), opacity: 1, bottom: 0}, 0.05);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
animation1();
animation2();
}, 1000);
```